# Extract HTML table using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a table from a web page. Below is the HTML and Python code using beautifulsoup. The code below always worked for me, but in this case I get blank. Thanks in advance.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Period Ending:</th>
<th class="TalignL">Trend</th>
<th>9/27/2014</th>
<th>9/28/2013</th>
<th>9/29/2012</th>
<th>9/24/2011</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#E6E6E6">Total Revenue</th>
<td class="td_genTable"><table border="0" align="center" width="*" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="bottom"><table border="0" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td height="15" bgcolor="#47C3D3" width="6"></td><td height="15" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="1px"></td></tr><tr><td height="1" colspan="2" bgcolor="#D1D1D1"></td></tr></table></td><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td height="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="6"></td><td height="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="1px"></td></tr><tr><td height="14" bgcolor="#47C3D3" width="6"></td><td height="14" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="1px"></td></tr><tr><td height="1" colspan="2" bgcolor="#D1D1D1"></td></tr></table></td><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td height="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="6"></td><td height="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="1px"></td></tr><tr><td height="13" bgcolor="#47C3D3" width="6"></td><td height="13" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="1px"></td></tr><tr><td height="1" colspan="2" bgcolor="#D1D1D1"></td></tr></table></td><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td height="7" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="6"></td><td height="7" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="1px"></td></tr><tr><td height="8" bgcolor="#47C3D3" width="6"></td><td height="8" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="1px"></td></tr><tr><td height="1" colspan="1" bgcolor="#D1D1D1"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>
<td>$182,795,000</td>
<td>$170,910,000</td>
<td>$156,508,000</td>
<td>$108,249,000</td>
```

```
    rows = table.findAll('tr')

    for row in rows:
        cols = row.findAll('td')
        col1 = [ele.text.strip().replace(',','') for ele in cols]

        account = col1[0:1]
        period1 = col1[2:3]
        period2 = col1[3:4]
        period3 = col1[4:5]

        record = (stock, account,period1,period3,period3)
        print record
```

Comment: Your first column of your first non-header row contains a table full of empty cells with no text in them. Your code is correctly finding that no text. I'm not sure what you wanted it to do instead.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you using the deprecated name `findAll`? Are you learning from sample code written for BS3 instead of from updated samples or documentation for BS4?

Comment: Finally, [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) (or `findAll`) searches through _all descendants_, not just the top-level children. So, unless you want to iterate through both the rows of the outer table and the rows of every subtable embedded inside a column of that table and treat them the same, you shouldn't be using it here.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @abarnert pointed out. I would get all the `td` elements with text starting with `$`:

```
for row in soup.table.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
    record = [td.text.replace(",", "") for td in row.find_all("td", text=lambda x: x and x.startswith("$"))]
    print record
```

For the input you've provided, it prints:

```
[u'$182795000', u'$170910000', u'$156508000', u'$108249000']
```

which you can "unpack" into separate variables:

```
account, period1, period2, period3 = record
```

Note that I'm explicitly passing `recursive=False` to avoid going deeper in the tree and get only direct `tr` children of the `table` element.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) (or `findAll`, which is just a deprecated synonym for the same thing) doesn't just find the rows in the table, it finds the rows in the table *and in every subtable within it*. You almost certainly don't want to iterate over both kinds of rows and run the same code on each one. If you don't want that, as [the `recursive` argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) docs say, pass `recursive=False`.

So, now you get back only one row. If you do `row.find_all('td')`, that's going to have the same problem again—you're going to find all of the columns of this row, and all of the columns of every row in every subtable within one of those columns. Again, that's not what you want, so use `recursive=False`.

And now you get back only 5 columns. The first one is just a big table with a bunch of empty cells in it; the others, on the other hand, have dollar values in them, which seem to be the ones you want.

---

So, just adding `recursive=False` to both calls, and setting `stock` to something (I don't know where it's supposed to come from in your code, but without it you're obviously going to just get a `NameError`):

```
stock = 'spam'

rows = table.find_all('tr', recursive=False)

for row in rows:
    cols = row.findAll('td', recursive=False)
    col1 = [ele.text.strip().replace(',','') for ele in cols]

    account = col1[0:1]
    period1 = col1[2:3]
    period2 = col1[3:4]
    period3 = col1[4:5]

    record = (stock, account,period1,period3,period3)

    print record
```

This will print:

```
('spam', [''], ['$170910000'], ['$108249000'], ['$108249000'])
```

I'm not sure why you used `period3` twice and never used `period2`, why you skipped over column 1 entirely, or why you sliced 1-element lists instead of just indexing the values, but anyway, this seems to be what you were trying to do.

---

As a side note, if you actually want to break out the list into 5 values, rather than into 4 1-element lists skipping one of the values, you can write:

```
account, whatever, period1, period2, period3 = col
```

Comment: @alecxe: To write books, you have to be able to edit things down. My chapter 1 would be 1300 pages. (That might work for a novel, but Tristam Shandy was already written 250 years ago…)

Comment: This worked!! Thank you. You are right. I am using stock as variable to loop through multiple stocks. Thanks again.